# Linear algebra: Let $A$ be a square matrix such that $A^{3} = I$, Find $\det A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the question:

**Let A be a square matrix such that $A^{3} = I$, Find $\det A$.**

As 
$$I=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
the $$A^{3} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

So is it just $\det A$ would be $\det A =\begin{vmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{vmatrix}$ ?

Thanks

Comment: Not only $A=I$ makes $A^3=I$. $\ \ $ I guess, you mean a matrix with *real* entries.

Comment: yepp thats correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all entries of A are real number then $\det (A)=1$. In fact
$$1=\det(I)=\det(A^3)=\det(A).\det(A).\det(A)=[\det(A)]^3.$$ So $\det(A)=\sqrt[3]{1}=1.$$

Comment: What about complex entries? Consider the diagonal matrix $e^{2\pi i/3}1$.

Comment: My work just restricts on the case of real entries.

Comment: Thank you all very much, really appreciated.